# Trying to partition aws linux server using shell script

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bash, partition, rhel7

When I created Amazon linux server(similar to Centos 7). I had these partitions
I am trying to create partitions using shell script
lsblk gives me following information

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1       259:0    0  80G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0  80G  0 part /
```

I have tried directly modifying fstab file and rebooting, that didnt help. Maybe I was doing something wrong in there

```
fstab file
UUID-xxxb /xfs defaults,noatime 1 1
UUID-xxxb /xfs defaults,noatime 1 2
UUID-xxxb /xfs defaults,noatime 1 3
```

I am trying to create partitions for /home , var, etc
thanks

Comment: Your disk seems to be completely allocated to a single parition. There is no space for additional partitions. Just deleting the current partition and create new ones will most probably wreck your installation. And yes, your fstab file has the wrong syntax.

Comment: You should add an EBS to your instance and then partition that instead of starting with the root disk given to you.  Or just use multiple EBS's.

Comment: Btw. there's no need to reboot after changing `/etc/fstab`: a simple `sudo mount -a` should do.